# How can I prove this statement about the BC Lemma?

Tags: measure-theory

[image]

This is what I am thinking:

Let $M< N <\infty $

$$P(\bigcap_{n=M}^N A_n^c) = \prod_{n=M}^N(1-P(A_n)) \leq \prod_{n=M}^N e^{(-P(A_n))}$$

$$= e^{\bigg( - \sum_{n=M}^N P(A_n)\bigg)} \rightarrow 0$$

as $N \rightarrow \infty$

So $$P(\bigcup_{n=M}^\infty A_n) = 1 \forall M$$ and since $$\bigcup_{n=M}^\infty A_n \downarrow \limsup A_n$$ it follows that

$$P(\limsup A_n) =1$$

So this statement would be the converse of what the question is asking right? Can someone please help me formulate this?

Comment: You seem to assume independence of the events without stating it anywhere.

Comment: you're right, i'm assuming independence from the 2nd bc lemma but i don't think it applies

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/312151/36150)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Independence is not required for this. Let $B_n=A_n\setminus (A_1\cup A_2\cup \cdots \cup A_{n-1})$. If possible let the conclusion  be false. Then $c \equiv P (\cup_n A_n) <1$. It is easy to verify that the events $B_n$ are disjoint and their union is same as $\cup_n A_n$. Hence $\sum_n P(B_n)<1$. Now $\sum_n P(A_n|\cap_{k<n}A_k^{c}) \leq \sum_n \frac {P(B_n)} {1-P(A_1\cup A_2 \cup \cdots )}=\frac c {1-c} <\infty$.

Comment: thank you, can you please explain what you mean by "if possible let the conclusion be false" ? Also why is $P(\cup_n A_n) < 1$?

Comment: @user477465  We want to prove that $P(\cap A_n^{c})=0$. If this is false then $P(\cap A_n^{c})>0$. Taking complement we get $P(\cup A_n)<1$.