# Showing that a martingale $Y_k$ does not converge almost surely.

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, martingales, almost-everywhere, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $X_i$ be iid with

$$\mathbb{P}(X_i=1)= \mathbb{P}(X_i= -1) = \frac{1}{2i}, \mathbb{P}(X_i=0)=1-\frac{1}{i},$$

where $i=1,2,...$

And define $Y_1=X_1$ and for $k\geq2$

$$Y_k=
\begin{cases}
X_k, \text{ if } Y_{k-1}=0\\ 
kY_{k-1}|X_k|, \text { if } Y_{k-1} \neq 0
\end{cases}
$$

I have shown that $Y_k$ is a martingale wrt to the natural filtration $\sigma(X_1,...,X_k)$.
And also that it converges in probability to zero (by conditioning on the events $(Y_{k-1} = 0 )$ and $(Y_{k-1} \neq0) $). I am however stuck on showing that it doesn't converge almost surely. I guess one has to use the Borell Cantelli Lemma but I don't see how to apply that in this situation.

Comment: What is $M_n$ ?

Comment: Yes sorry, that should be $Y_k$

Answer (score 3):

One can show that
$$\Bbb P(Y_k\neq0\mid X_0,\ldots,X_{k-1})=\frac1k$$
for all $k\ge1$.
Thus $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\Bbb P(Y_k\neq0\mid X_0,\ldots,X_{k-1})=\infty.$$
By the [conditional Borel-Cantelli lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312151/generalized-second-borel-cantelli-lemma), this means that the event $\limsup\:\{Y_k\neq0\}=\limsup\:\{|Y_k|\ge1\}$ is almost sure.